# Samba share quit on me today

Tags: 18.04, xubuntu, samba

Ubuntu 18.04, Samba has been working for months, this morning I try to access from my windows 10 machine and it says it is not reachable. I am a newby, I have searched and checked threads, tried a bunch of things, have not come up with an answer. Ideas? Here is my config file

```
[global]
   client min protocol = SMB2
   client max protocol = SMB3
   server role = standalone server
   workgroup = WORKGROUP
   server string = Samba Server %v
   netbios name = Kodi Server
   dns proxy = no
   security = user
   map to guest = bad user
#   wins support = yes
#   wins server = w.x.y.z
   #local master = yes
   #preferred master = yes
   bind interfaces only = yes

[Media]
   comment = NAS Media
   path = /media/shane/media
   read only = no
   browsable = yes
   writeable = yes
   guest ok = yes
   public = yes

[Files]
   comment = NAS Files
   path = /media/shane/files
   read only = no
   browsable = yes
   writeable = yes
   guest ok = yes
   public = yes
```

Comment: If it was working, maybe the problem is network related, not samba. Can you ping the server machine and get a response?

Comment: It is not the network as my NFS shares still work just fine between my other linux machines.

Answer (score 1):

What I'm trying to figure out is how your setup ever worked.

Both your shared folders are under /media/shane - and I'm assuming "shane" is your user name. Linux sets special permissions on that folder such that only shane can traverse it to get to what is under it. The samba guest user is not shane so it will never get access.

The only way this could have worked is if the Windows user was also named "shane" and the samba password for that user on your server was an exact match to the login password for shane on the Win10 box.

For future compatibility I would edit your share definitions and add a line to force the samba client user to appear as shane to Linux - at least for these shares: `force user = shane`. For example:

```
[Media]
   comment = NAS Media
   path = /media/shane/media
   read only = no
   browsable = yes
   writeable = yes
   guest ok = yes
   public = yes
   force user = shane
```

Then restart smbd.

The other thing is the space in your netbios name. I've never seen a space in a hostname or netbios name. Maybe samba concatenates the two and creates kodiserver instead. I honestly don't know.

Comment: Ok I will try that when I get home, thank you